# Kane and Lynch split screen

Tags: kane-and-lynch-2

Does anyone know which way the split screen on Kane & Lynch 2 will be orientated? As in, will it be side by side, or one on top of the other (like in Halo)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that [Kane & Lynch: Dead Men had vertical (side-by-side) split screen](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=349MmE0xkOI), I would bet that it's the same for Kane & Lynch 2: Dog Days.  Both games use the Glacier Engine and changing it seems like an esoteric change to make.

Answer (score 1):

I've since seen in the gametrailers review for K&L2 that the split screen is in the classical horizontal form...

Answer (score -2):

there is no splitscreen in second part of Kane and Lynch adventure